# Finding if string has element from list and returning that element from list

Tags: python, pandas, performance

Currently I'm struggling to find an elegant way to program a problem I'm facing.

I have a large dataframe, containing a column with Department names:

##### INPUT

```
demo = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Department':
        ['AA','AA1','BB team 1','AA but also a bit of nonsense',
        'BB','AA','department BB','Complete nonsense']}
    )
```

```
Department
AA
AA1
BB team 1
AA but also a bit of nonsense
BB
AA
department BB 
Complete nonsense
```

I also have a list of known departments:

`known_departments = ['AA','BB']`

As one can see, there are three type of departments in the list:

1. Departments that are exact matches with known departments, these should stay untouched.
2. Departments that are variants of the known departments. *That is: it contains the department name, but some other text is present.* These should be mapped to the original known departments.
3. Complete nonsense departments, with no match whatsoever with the known departments, these should stay untouched as well.

##### Desired output

```
Department                      Department_simplified
AA                              AA
AA1                             AA
BB team 1                       BB
AA but also a bit of nonsense   AA
BB                              BB
AA                              AA
department BB                   BB
Complete nonsense               Complete nonsense
```

##### UPDATE

Thanks Chris and sophocles for your answers. While looking more elegant by using `str.extract` and `str.findall`, performance-wise the apply+function outperforms both on my actual df:

```
Solution    %%timeit -n20
Chris       1.65s ± 311 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20 loops each)
sophocles   1.14s ± 294 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20 loops each)
Paul        680 ms ± 174 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20 loops each)
```

Comment: Does this get you started? there are some vectorised solutions, too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590488/map-str-contains-across-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I'll take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: @CallumDA. this works, but is the same solution as my answer below. I guess I'm more interested in the vectorised solutions.

Comment: what are statistics? how often department is same as department_simplified? how many departments are there? how long is average department name, how long is average department_simplified?

Answer (score 0):

I currently use apply in combination with a function to get my result.

Code:

```
def item_in_string(string, list_of_items):
    for item in list_of_items:
        if item in string:
            return item
    return string

demo['Department_simplified'] = demo.Department.apply(
    lambda x: item_in_string(x, known_departments) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

However, this does not feel very efficient, nor pythonic.

I was wondering if someone has a better way to program this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.extract` here, and build a list of deparments separated by `|` (or) as the pattern.

```
import pandas as pd

known_departments = ['AA','BB']

demo = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Department':
        ['AA','AA1','BB team 1','AA but also a bit of nonsense',
        'BB','AA','department BB','Complete nonsense']}
    )

demo['Department_simplified'] = demo.Department.str.extract(f"({'|'.join(known_departments)})")

# If you need to fill nulls with the original dept name
demo['Department_simplified'].fillna(demo['Department'], inplace=True)

print(demo)
```

Output

```
    Department Department_simplified
0                             AA                    AA
1                            AA1                    AA
2                      BB team 1                    BB
3  AA but also a bit of nonsense                    AA
4                             BB                    BB
5                             AA                    AA
6                  department BB                    BB
7              Complete nonsense     Complete nonsense
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first use `str.findall` to return the matching substrings of your Department column with your list elements (known_departments). For the ones that nothing is returned, you just use the values in Department, as there's no match whatsoever

```
demo['Department_simplified'] = demo['Department']\
    .str.findall('|'.join(known_departments)).str.join('')

demo['Department_simplified'] = np.where(
    demo['Department_simplified'].eq(''),demo['Department'],demo['Department_simplified'])
```

Prints:

```
                      Department Department_simplified
0                             AA                    AA
1                            AA1                    AA
2                      BB team 1                    BB
3  AA but also a bit of nonsense                    AA
4                             BB                    BB
5                             AA                    AA
6                  department BB                    BB
7              Complete nonsense     Complete nonsense
```