# Create Pandas DataFrame column based on substring values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to assign values to the 'group' column of the Pandas DataFrame based on the substring from another column. Example DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

groups = ['custumer', 'supplier', 'irrelevant', 'spam', 'invoice', 'shipping advice']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'mailLabels': ['customers/AcmeBar', 'suppliers/AcmeBaz', 'irrelevant', 'spam', 'invoice', 'shipping advice' ],
    'group': ['na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na', 'na']})
```

My solution works but it is extremely cumbersome as the number of groups is much bigger than in this example:

```
df['group'] = pd.np.where(df.mailLabels.str.contains("customer"), "sales",
                               pd.np.where(df.mailLabels.str.contains("supplier"), "procurement",
                               pd.np.where(df.mailLabels.str.contains("irrelevant"), "not important",
                               pd.np.where(df.mailLabels.str.contains("spam"), "not important", "other"))))

print(df)

          mailLabels          group
0  customers/AcmeBar          sales
1  suppliers/AcmeBaz    procurement
2         irrelevant  not important
3               spam  not important
4            invoice          other
5    shipping advice          other
```

Is there a vectorised solution to this problem? [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510405/pandas-python-dataframe-update-a-column/48510563#48510563) does not work as I cannot split mailLabels column due to a messy data.

Comment: see `np.select`.

Comment: how many groups do you have? Are the groups mapped a key in a dict?

Comment: I have 31 groups in a list but I could map them in a dict if this would help.

Comment: @YO and BEN_W I checked [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) but I could not find any reference to my real problem, matching substring.